# Check if the new SRC is loaded

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading, src

My img tag have :

- a `data-src` which is the HD image
- an `src` which is very small version of the HD image (< 2kb), just to give the correct img ratio.

Then, I have done a small lazy load function like this :

```
function lazyLoad() {
    document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(img => {
        new IntersectionObserver( (entries, observer) => {
            entries.forEach(entry => {
                if ((entry.isIntersecting) && (img.dataset.src)) {
                    img.src = img.dataset.src;
                    function loadImage(callback) {
                        img.src = img.dataset.src;
                        if (img.onload = true) {
                            callback();
                        }
                    };
                    function showImage() {
                            img.classList.add("visible"); //this fade in the image 0 -> 1
                            img.removeAttribute('data-src');
                            observer.disconnect();
                    };
                    loadImage(showImage);
                };
            });
        }, {rootMargin: '500px'} ).observe(img);
    });
};
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', lazyLoad);
```

What I want to do is that when the **new** src that is applied (img.src = img.dataset.src), callback to the fadeIn by adding the class.
Right Now it doesn't really work since an src is already loaded. What did I do wrong ?

Thanks ! :)

Comment: Replace the `if (img.onload = true) { callback() }` block with `img.onload = callback;` 1) that's not how onload works 2. comparisons are done using `==` or `===` 3. having to use a callback is precisely because you cannot set the src then immediately check whether it has loaded; loading the src will take some time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that !!! I'll keep that in mind.